# "Go on holiday in the mountains" or "go on holiday to the mountains"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do use to say that I like go on holiday where the mountains are: *in* or *to*? For example:

> I like going on holiday **in** the mountains.
>
> I like going on holiday **to** the mountains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *go* on holiday *to*  the mountains (travel there for the purpose of taking a holiday), but you could also take a holiday, or spend your holiday,  *in* the mountains. (This is not to say that no-one would ever say *go on holiday in*…)